# Charged for PS4 free games. Why?

Tags: ps4, uncharted-4

I purchased Uncharted-4 Free game from PS Store on April 28th, 2020. I got billed full amount even though it's free. I don't have PS+ account. Will I get a refund? I haven't downloaded the game yet on my PS4.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I dont have PSpLus account.

That's the problem. Uncharted 4 is not free, it has become a PS Plus game for April 2020.

[image: Screenshot of Uncharted 4 store page]

In other words, it's free for any PS Plus subscriber that redeemed the game in April 2020, and as long as they pay for PS Plus.

At this point, the only thing you can do is contact Sony and explain your situation to them. There is no guarantee they'll give you a refund, however.

#### EDIT:

Due to some recent comment, I'm beginning to see the bigger picture. There's been a misunderstanding on which game is currently free.

It is not [Uncharted 4](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA00341_00-UNCHARTED0000000), that's free, but [Uncharted: The Nathan Drake Collection](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA02320_00-UNCHARTEDTRILOGY), which only includes the first three games.

[image: Screenshot of Uncharted: The Nathan Drake Collection store page]

Explaining the misunderstanding to Sony may improve your chances at getting a refund, but again, there is no guarantee they'll give you one.

Comment: I have checked the wonky blog too. They clearly said that these games don't need PS+. I already wrote customer service. I believe it shall be refunded. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKxyem.jpg

Comment: @ShahilShah if you read [the blog](https://www.techradar.com/au/news/sony-is-encouraging-social-distancing-by-gifting-two-free-ps4-games) it says *"The games up for grabs include **Uncharted: The Nathan Drake Collection** that rounds up the first three games in the series and remasters them for the PS4, as well as the PS4 port of **Journey.** "*, the game you bought that was free for PS+ is Uncharted 4

Comment: Since the OP has stated they have not downloaded the game yet, they should be able to get a refund fairly easily. See [How to request a refund for PlayStation Store purchases](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Requesting-a-Refund)

Answer (score 14):

Since you haven't downloaded the game yet, you should be able to get a refund:

> Refunds for Games, DLC, Add-ons
>
> ...
>
> After purchasing this type of content through PlayStation™Store, you have 14 days from purchase to request a refund to your payment method on PlayStation™Network. If you started to download or stream the purchased content you are not eligible for a refund unless the content is faulty.

From [How to request a refund for PlayStation Store purchases](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Requesting-a-Refund?language=en_US)